# how can I put a variable in an sql command string in vba access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
letter=65
```

is a variable representing a letter (A) in the alphabet.
I want to insert letter into part of an sql command string:
    `sqlUrlCount = "SELECT tblMain.Name FROM tblMain WHERE (((tblMain.Name) Like     '" & Chr(letter) & "*'))"`

but I get an error: "Run-time error '3075': Syntax error in string in query expression '(((tblMain.Name) Like".

this is probably because of the quotes and double quotes I used. but how else can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to create a field called 'Name' in Access it complained that it was a reserved word - could be part of the problem.

The code below returned an SQL string which worked when I pasted it into the query window (note - have updated 'Name' to 'sName' and the field type is Text).
Also note - Access loves putting brackets around everything and most of the time they're not required.

```
Sub test()

    Dim letter As Long
    Dim sqlUrlCount As String

    letter = 65

    sqlUrlCount = "SELECT sName FROM tblMain WHERE sName Like '" & Chr(letter) & "*'"

End Sub
```

**Edit:**
To use a SELECT query:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim sqlUrlCount As String
    Dim letter As Long
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    letter = 65

    sqlUrlCount = "SELECT tblNewMain.WebAddressCompareString, " & _
        "Count(*) AS [How Many?] FROM tblNewMain " & _
        "WHERE (((tblNewMain.WebAddressCompareString) Like '" & Chr(letter) & "*')) " & _
        "GROUP BY tblNewMain.WebAddressCompareString HAVING (((Count(*))>1))"

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlUrlCount)

    With rst
        If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
            .MoveFirst
            Do
                Debug.Print .Fields("WebAddressCompareString") & " : " & .Fields(1)
                .MoveNext
            Loop Until .EOF
        End If
        .Close
    End With

    Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

If it's a DDL or DML type query - i.e. UPDATE, CREATE TABLE, SELECT INTO, etc then you can use `DoCmd.RunSQL`

Comment: In the real code it is not "tblMain,Name". I rewrote the code so that my question would be clearer. I am putting the real code here: `sqlUrlCount = "SELECT tblNewMain.WebAddressCompareString, Count(*) AS [How Many?] FROM tblNewMain WHERE (((tblNewMain.WebAddressCompareString) Like '" & Chr(letter) & "*')) GROUP BY tblNewMain.WebAddressCompareString HAVING (((Count(*))>1))" `

Comment: That string is fine - using CHR(34) - a double quote, will return error 2342, CHR(39) - a single quote, returns error 3075.  Ahhh.... think I've got it.  Are you using **DoCmd.RunSQL** to execute the statement? That only works on action type queries - UPDATE, CREATE TABLE, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct so try to copy-n-paste the resulting string:

```
SELECT tblMain.Name FROM tblMain WHERE (((tblMain.Name) Like 'A*'))
```

into a new query.

If it fails, adjust the SQL and then your code.

If it runs, then rewrite your code line (no copy-n-paste), then delete the old code line.

Comment: What i mean is; it works fine with the `like 'A*'` but the minute I change it to the dynamic version i get the message.

Comment: Then `letter` probably doesn't hold a valid value. Try to print out the string before running the query: `Debug.Print sqlUrlCount` and tell us what you see.